# Import Database in VS 2015 SQL Server Database Project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

I recently had troubles Importing a Database from a SQL Server Database Project in VS 2015. Just hoping this helps some folks. I will add more pictures when my rep is higher.

Error I get: 
**The server version or database compatibility level is not supported.**

This is the Error I get when I right click on the project and try and **Import a Database**. Import Error:
[image]

Comment: Had a chance to update my post. I have seen Stack Over users post helpers like this before. Just thought I'd be able to help more people. Is there another place to post helpers on Stack Over?

Comment: Either way, glad you posted because it helped me.

Comment: @DerekEscue Please reformat this so that you only mention your issue in the original post. Then answer your own question with your resolution in the Answer box below. That is the Stack Overflow format. You will then get points for your question and also your correct answer.

Answer (score 46):

[image: Start]

Right click on the **Project** and clicking **View in Object Explorer**.
[image: Step1]

Add and connect to your database next, if needed. Right click on the database you are wanting to import and click **Create New Project**.
[image: Step2]

Change settings if needed. Then Click **Start**
[image: Step4]

Comment: Thanks. this was a super helpful post

Comment: Thank you! You save a lot of our time!

Comment: Great workaround to an annoying bug - thanks!  Please mark your answer as the answer (click the check mark next to the answer score) as that will help others find this.

Comment: Again I want to give plus 1, one question is as above , how we know which framework is required for this db

Comment: tried your approach, however it fails with "Failed to detect database version" under Visual Studio 2017

Comment: @nojetlag I haven't used this is a while, give me a couple days and I will try to give it a try

Comment: @DerekEscue Found the problem, installing Visual Studio 2017 with the web installer doesn't give the latest version (had a different expectation for a web installer), rather it needs another 2 GB of updates and then it worked :)

Comment: @nojetlag Nice! Glad you found a solution.

Comment: @Derek Escue, i tried to import Database using your specified approach in VS2015. It didn't succeed. I'm just able to load as project in Object Explorer. Any suggestion please?

Comment: @Shalem I haven't used this is a while, give me a couple days and I will try to give it a try

Answer (score 1):

Once you open Visual Studio – go to the menu: File -> New -> Project. A new window will be opened and then find the project type: SQL Server Database Project. 
Having an empty database project you can either create new objects and create a new database from scratch or import existing ones. Please follow the below steps:

1. Create a new SQL project in the Visual Studio solution
2. Right-click the new SQL project and choose Import -> Database
3. Select the database you want to import and click Start
4. Repeat steps 1-3 above for the History database (IF available)
5. Add a database reference to the main database that points to the history database
   a. Database reference to a project in the current solution
   b. The database location is “different database, same server”
   c. Replace any periods in the Database variable with underscores. Periods are not supported in the variable name.
6. Right-click the main SQL project and go to Properties -> SQLCMD Variables
   a. Add the name of the History database to the Local column of the entry for the History database (something like “Database_History”)
7. Replace all instances of the History database name with the History database variable
   a. This occurred at the bottom of the table scripts, where the triggers were generated.
   b. The correct syntax should look something like this: [$(Database_History)].Schema.TableName
8. Ensure both SQL projects will build successfully
   a. There were some cases where I had to explicitly specify the table in which a column appears 
   (ex. ImageID -> REPORTS.Image.ImageID in a stored procedure)
   b. There were some instances where a stored procedure or a view referred to a column that no longer exists
   i. Change the Build Action to None
   c. There were some instances where the project wants to create users for people who are no longer with the company.
   i. Change the Build Action to None.
9. Check for differences between the Visual Studio project and the deployed database (if any development happened between you importing the database and finishing the steps above)
   a. Generate a publish script targeting the deployed database. Anything the script attempts to modify is a difference you should obtain from the deployed database.
   i. Do not revert any changes made in step 8
10. Publish the databases to an existing deployed location and ensure functionality remains.